# My bluetooth module keeps sending out constant exports

Tags: arduino-uno, led, bluetooth

So I have a bluetooth module hooked up to my arduino to control an LED light, something simple to turn on and off. But the app im using constantly is either sending something or receiving. This causes the circuit to not work at all and I cannot figure out what is going on.

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
   if(Serial.available()>0)
      {
         char data= Serial.read();
         switch(data)
            {
               case 'a': digitalWrite(8, HIGH);break;
               case 'd': digitalWrite(8, LOW);break;
               default : break;
            }
         Serial.println(data);
      }
      delay(50);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your Arduino code is only sending, if it received some data. We don't know your app, so it might be constantly sending data. You could test that by connecting TX of the bluetooth module to TX on the Arduino, holding it in reset and then look at the Serial monitor, what was received there. (or you can use a sketch with a SoftwareSerial interface)

Comment: If you send a char from your app, you will send such char plus '\n' or '\r\ or both. For each char your sketch will print a (blank) line.

Comment: enable hex rx in your app ... i think that it will allow you to see non-printing characters